# Same GPU for both computation and display

Tags: display, gpu

I'm doing some shopping trying to get a GPU that will be used for computation (I'm trying to learn GPU programming), gaming and general display, since the computer's motherboard doesn't have integrated graphics.

My question is - When I run GPU computations on the graphics card can it still be used as a display adapter. The computer has no integrated graphics to that card is currently the only way of getting a display output.

Comment: Computations will run in the CUDA cores (if using an nVidia card), the discreet GPU will have sufficient processing power to also service your OS & UI for non-computational activities.

Comment: Your computer needs two graphical adapters for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

While there are some configurations, such as enabling TCC mode, that would prevent display output from working, they aren't generally necessary for GPU computing.

Comment: We use some custom vision code that uses the GPU and there are no problems with it serving our touchscreen monitor as well.  Good answer.